# how it is possible to run two iteration of a for loop at a same time?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to do something in each iteration of my for loop. but it should be done at the same time (together) not back to back. Is there any way to do that.

I tried using thread but it seems that it doesn't work.

```
seen_events=[]    
def loop_recursive(self, time, events, time_stamp, directory_new):
    if time.start_time == time_stamp and time_stamp not in self.seen_events:
        for item in events:
            self.seen_events.append(item.time_stamp)
            self.activate_event(item)
```

There are 2 item in events, I want to for each item call the `self.activate_event()` function at the same time, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is events a list of lists?
If yes, it's only to do:

```
for item1,item2 in events:
    ...
    self.activate_event(item1)
    self.activate_event(item2)
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, No it is list of event(object).